# Problems while importing an image asset

Tags: android, image, android-image

I'm trying to import a PNG image asset to my project. But the image is losing details.  It's just retaining the outer background. The image is transformed to a solid asset:

[image]

As you can see, the source asset has a white-tick in the center. But, after importing, it just remains as a solid circle with no ticks. Any solutions?

**UPDATE:** Tried Android asset studio, but with the same result. What am I missing?:

[image]

Comment: Try changing the custom color or the theme or google android asset studio to create much better image for your app

Comment: yeah, already tried that changing the custom color. still the same result. color changes, but the white tick doesn't appear. I'll update after trying the google asset studio.

Comment: @ShafayatMamun, no luck with the asset studio too. updated the question.

Comment: Set custom color to 0%

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: Do you see the bar beside the color? Take it all the way down to 0

Comment: In android asset studio. Do you see the bar with 100% on it beside the custom color? Take it all the way down to 0.

Comment: Thankyou, that worked. I had to select `Generic Icons` instead of `Action bar and tab icons`, and then sliding the color down to 0% worked.

Comment: Can you please share your image?

Comment: @ShafayatMamun, you can download from this link: https://dropmefiles.com/VtCIr

Comment: Yeah, this is strange. Only when choosing action bar the whole icon gets filled. I hope someone else has a more valid response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Shafayat Mamun, a workaround is figured out. Here's what I did:

1. Go to [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html)
2. Select Generic Icons (it didn't work for any other option)
3. Upload the image, pick your color and drag down the color scale to 0% using the scale.
4. Download the zip and extract to the main folder of the project.

**PS:** This, though helped me solve my query, but the question remains intact. Why is android studio not capturing the image details while importing? Same is the case while I select `Action bar and tab icons` in the Android Asset Studio.

Answer (score 0):

do you really need to convert it in the action bar and tab icon generator? i recommend using the simple nine-patch generator [here](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) if you want a 9patch image. or the [launcher icon generator](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html) and set the shape to none and change the image's name after downloading. if you use the launcher icon generator, just modify the shape. if you use the nine-patch generator, you can click trim and click edge transparency if you want to remove the spaces beside the image.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the workaround has already been figured out. The question that remains is why can't I import it as Action bar and tab icons.

Comment: maybe because of how the site create the icon, it seems that the site fills the icon with a certain color that's why the tick on the center of your image disappeared

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the Android Asset Studio workaround was a great help. However I discovered another work around. In Android Studio when you create an image asset, instead of selecting Action Bar and Tab icons, I chose Launcher Icons from the drop down. Then the images displayed for me. I had to search for their name and they do not get stored in the drawable folder they end up in the mipmap folder.

So the steps are:
For Android Studio:

Right click on res, new Image Asset

On Asset type choose Launcher Icons

Choose the image path
Give your image a name in Resource name
Next->Finish

The image will be saved in the /res/mipmap folder